# Speed up Animation for UIPickerView Scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uipickerview

Currently, when selecting components or swiping the UIPickerView, the default is a lengthy animation time waiting for the selection, with a "gravity" effect near values. Is there a simple way to speed up this animation? I've looked at the delegate protocols as well as UIPickerView's methods and properties. Will I have to subclass and overload the animation method? Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  If you'd like for there to be a way to do this, please [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) asking for it.

Also, relying on implementation details and a particular interval view hierarchy, as Fabian suggests, is a really excellent way to introduce a ton of fragility into your application and open the possibility of your app breaking in the future, should UIKit ever change anything.

Comment: Still no way :/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to achieve that using public API, but `UIPickerView` uses a `UIPickerTableView` as a subview somewhere in its view hierarchy. That is a subclass of `UITableView` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView` which has a `decelerationRate` property.

You shouldn't use private API, though. If you really need this and it's not for an App Store app this might be okay, but you should be careful and code defensively.

Comment: +1 correct there's no way to do this.  -1 for suggesting that he poke around in private view hierarchies.  So... +0 overall. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 rep, so can't comment on this (which is where this should really go).  This question shouldn't have been downvoted since the question is legitimate.  The valid answer is "no, you can't do that without private API hacks"), but the question is still valid.

Comment: congrats on 50!